# How to Query Exists and Not Exists from Same Table, Using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

I have a table that has a list of PartIds and AccountIds associated with those parts. In that table, there is a boolean that determines whether the PartId/AccountId pairing are a member of an exclusive club (IsInExclusiveClub).

I want to query the table to find the distinct PartId/AccountId pairing for both belonging to the exclusive club and not belonging to the exclusive club.

Here are the two SQL queries that I have written to do this:

**For being IN the exclusive club:**

```
DECLARE                           @ForeignPassedInKey int; set @ForeignPassedInKey = [Some Integer]

SELECT                     DISTINCT p.PartId
FROM                       dbo.Part p
WHERE                      IsInExclusiveClub = 1
AND                        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Parts p2 
                                  WHERE p.partid = p2.partid 
                                  AND p2.Account IN (SELECT AccountId FROM dbo.Accounts
                                                               WHERE ForeignPassedInKey = @ForeignPassedInKey)
                                  AND p2.IsInExclusiveClub = 1)
```

**For being excluded from the exclusive club:**

```
DECLARE                           @ForeignPassedInKey int; set @ForeignPassedInKey = [Some Integer]

SELECT                     DISTINCT p.PartId
FROM                       dbo.Part p
WHERE                      IsInExclusiveClub = 1
AND                        NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Parts p2 
                                  WHERE p.partid = p2.partid 
                                  AND p2.Account IN (SELECT AccountId FROM dbo.Accounts
                                                               WHERE ForeignPassedInKey = @ForeignPassedInKey)
                                  AND p2.IsInExclusiveClub = 1)
```

How would I write that using Linq to Entities. Also, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Your exits/not exists query and outer query look like they're almost the same.  Why are you using exist/not exist anyways?  Why not just add the account part of the exits/not exists where clause into the outer query?

Comment: Can you show me what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query could be simplified by doing this:

```
SELECT                  DISTINCT p.PartId
FROM                    dbo.Part p
WHERE                   IsInExclusiveClub = 1
AND                     Account IN (SELECT AccountId FROM dbo.Accounts WHERE ForeignPassedInKey = @ForeignPassedInKey)
```

For the NOT EXISTS Query, you would change it to "Account NOT IN".

The Linq query for this could look like:

```
var accounts = db.Accounts
                .Where(account => account.ForeignPassedInKey = ForeignPassedInKey)
                .Select(account => account.AccountId);
var parts = db.Parts
                .Where(part => part.IsInExclusiveClub = 1 && accounts.Contains(part.AccountId))
                .Select(part => partId).Distinct();
```

Then !accounts.Contains(part.AccountID) for the NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

This is the general idea on how to do an "Exists" query:

```
var query = from s in this.CDSEntityManager.Context.cust_task
                     join g in this.CDSEntityManager.Context.cust_task_group on s.cust_task_group_id equals g.cust_task_group_id
                     where s.cust_id == currentAccount.cust_id && g.complaint_flag == true
                     select s;

var isComplaintCustomer = (await query.ExecuteAsync()).Any();
```

The basic idea is:  1. Construct your query.  2. Execute with `Any()`.